# How to transition a UICollectionViewCell via a button to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift3

**Question:**

**How do I transition a UICollectionViewCell I've assigned a button for a UICollection to another View Controller?**

**Summary:**

1. I've created a UICollection, and UICollectionCells for each image I have.
2. I create a CollectionCell object for each image I find.
3. I'm able to create images and buttons for each object, but once I set the target of the button for the cell, I cannot redirect to another ViewController.

**Attempts:**

I read some other attempts, but they all required that the function be called from the original view controller.

**Starting the view controller from within the current view controller:**

```
let secondViewController:SecondViewController = SecondViewController()

    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

**Calling a function from the view controller:**

```
button.addTarget(self,action:#selector(YourControllerName.buttonClicked(_:)),
                         forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

**Current Code:**

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var text: String!
    var image_view: UIImageView!
    var button: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print("Number:" + card_text)

        image_view = UIImageView(frame: contentView.frame)
        image_view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        mage_view.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(image_view)

        let x_value = contentView.frame.width - contentView.frame.width
        let y_value = (contentView.frame.height)/3
        let rectangle = CGRect(x: x_value, y: y_value, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 40)
        button = UIButton(frame: rectangle)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        button.setTitle(card_text, for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.addTarget(self,action: #selector(ObjectViewCell.buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        contentView.addSubview(button)
    }

    func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Practicing: " + self.card_text)
    }
}






class Selector: UIViewController
{
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let base_image = UIImage(named: "blank")
    var images = [UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank"), UIImage(named: "blank")]

    @IBOutlet weak var main_view: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Loading view in Selector")
        setupCollectionView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setupCollectionView() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        // Add spacing around each cell.
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10

        // Set each cell size to the size of the image.
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: (base_image?.size.width)!, height: (base_image?.size.height)!)

        // Set the collection view to the size of the view frame.
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: main_view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        // Register all images with the CollectionViewCell object.
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        // Set the background color.
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        // Add the collections view to the main view.
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
}


extension Selector: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.card_text = String(indexPath.item + 1)
        cell.awakeFromNib()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cardCell = cell as! ObjectViewCell
        cardCell.image_view.image = images[indexPath.row]
    }
```

**Update:**

Here is what I ended up doing. I read over everybody's comments and answers, and I resolved to make all necessary changes within the view controller who originates the UICollection cells. Therefore, I moved my logic out of the CollectionViewCell object, and instead perform all logic/subview additions in the initialization of the cells.

Now I just need to figure out how to transition a view controller. Thank you everyone.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let contentView = cell.contentView
        let image_view = UIImageView(image: base_image)

        image_view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image_view.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(image_view)

        let x_value = contentView.frame.width - contentView.frame.width
        let y_value = (contentView.frame.height)/3
        let rectangle = CGRect(x: x_value, y: y_value, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 40)
        let button = UIButton(frame: rectangle)

        let text = String(indexPath.item + 1)
        button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
        button.accessibilityHint = text
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        contentView.addSubview(button)
        return cell
    }



func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Button pressed")
        print(sender.accessibilityHint)

        //let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
        // 2. Present the navigation controller
        //self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that your `buttonPressed` doesnt do anything.

Comment: I know that! Because I removed my attempts at transitioning to another view controller. I get compilation errors.

Comment: You shouldn't call `awakeFromNib` yourself; this will result in your cell getting multiple subviews when it is reused. You need to keep a property in your cell that refers to the existing textfield and update that when the text property is changed, using a setter

Comment: @Paulw11 I can see why adding multiple subviews would be bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your button's target is the cell, and so the `buttonPressed` action function is located in the cell. That's a pretty silly thing to do, because (as you rightly say) you cannot call `present` without a view controller to send it to.

What I would have done is set the button's target/selector in `cellForItemAt:`. That way, `self` *is* the view controller and we can set the target to `self`. But you didn't do that!

Thus, you need to get from the cell to the view controller that controls it.

However, there is a way. It's called *walking the responder chain*. Set a UIResponder variable to the button:

```
var responder : UIResponder = self
```

Now loop, calling `next` on `responder` to walk one step up the chain:

```
responder = responder.next
```

Each time, look to see if this responder is a UIViewController. When it is, stop looping and send it `present`! Thus:

```
var responder : UIResponder = self
repeat { responder = responder .next } while !(responder is UIViewController)
let vc = responder as! UIViewController
vc.present( // ...
```

(Still, even though the problem can be solved in this way, I think it was silly to get yourself into this mess in the first place. Making the view controller the target in the first place would have been a much better idea, in my opinion.)

Comment: I am not a fan either of these solutions.  1) proper encapsulation dictates that the ViewController doesn't go riffling through the CollectionViewCell's properties, 2) walking up the responder chain to find your parent view controller is super hacky.  Use the delegate pattern; its what everyone expects in Cocoa.  The cell figures out the details of how the user wants to navigate to a detail view and it tells the ViewController and the ViewController does it.  The two are loosely coupled and maintain a separation of concerns and the ViewController knows nothing about button press details.

Comment: @JoshHomann I see what you're saying. The way I'm going about it is I'm circumventing the MVC. Instead, I should allow the view controller to control the transition instead of attempting to allow the cell to determine that logic. Do you happen to know how I go about doing it this way? Ideally, I'd like to send the user to a different view depending on which button they press. It could be a single view that takes a single parameter.

Comment: @JoshHomann I don't agree at all! The cell is view, pure and simple. The view controller is controller; _it_ should do the thinking. And the view controller _qua_ data source most certainly _does_ go riffling through the cell's properties; that is _exactly_ what it does.